# Copy images to device in debug build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am working on an application in React Native.

I have an issue where images aren't loading because a view containing images is [intentionally] loaded once and does not re-render, therefore not loading the images as they load too late.

This isn't a problem when running a release build, because assets such as images are loaded straight onto the device, instead of streaming them through Metro Bundler.

How can I re-create the same behaviour as release mode so that images are copied to the device when testing, but so I can still access development features such as live reload?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the indicator visible while the image is loaded. Otherwise, we can solve this problem through a cache.

**Usage Cache**

- `default`: Use the native platforms default strategy.
- `reload`: The data for the URL will be loaded from the originating
  source. No existing cache data should be used to satisfy a URL load
  request.
- `force-cache`: The existing cached data will be used to satisfy the
  request, regardless of its age or expiration date. If there is no
  existing data in the cache corresponding the request, the data is
  loaded from the originating source.
- `only-if-cached`: The existing cache data will be used to satisfy a
  request, regardless of its age or expiration date. If there is no
  existing data in the cache corresponding to a URL load request, no
  attempt is made to load the data from the originating source, and the
  load is considered to have failed.

```js
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png',
    cache: 'force-cache',
  }}
  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
/>
```

**Usage Load Image**// Suppose you use an indicator.

```js
this.state={
  loading : true,
  imageUrl :  { uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png' }
}

  _onLoad = () => {
     this.setState({ loading: false })
  }

  _onError = () => {
      this.setState({ 
                      loading: false,
                      imageUrl : require('./assets/defaultImage.png')
                   })
  }

<Image
  source={this.state.imageUrl}
  onLoad={this._onLoad}
  onError={this._onError}
  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
/>
```